# How to check if folder is empty?

Tags: node.js, protractor

I need to check if folder is empty and sent one email if is empty and another if is not.

Email settings are set correctly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an e2e test at all, so to be executed through protractor. 
Why the `protractor` tag is needed?

Comment: let me know if this answer was helpful to you.

Comment: @quirimmo After I run all tests in protractor I sent email with attached html, but when tests for some reason didn't execute - the folder is empty I sent another email. I agree it is not connected to tests...

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal it was helpful, thanks

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I don't know how to do that?

Comment: @SanjaPaskova refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `readdir` of `fs`

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
fs.readdir(folderName, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
       // some sort of error
    } else {
       if (!files.length) {
           // directory appears to be empty so send email for empty
       } else {
          // directory appears to not be empty so send email for not empty
        }
    }
});
```